# How can I join a df made in iteration, to build a big df?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to biuld a "big" df using the df_temp I am getting in every iteration

IN:

```
df_data = {
            'Code':[data['code']],
            'Buy_date':[date_ex_dividend],
            'Buy':[round(df.loc[date_ex_dividend]['Open'],2)],
            'Sell_date':[date_pay_dividend],
            'Sell':[round(df.loc[date_pay_dividend]['Close'],2)],
            'Div_profit':[data['profit']],
            'Gap':[round(sell-bank,2)],
            'TOTAL_PROFIT':[round(sell-bank + (bank*percent/100),2)],
        }
        df_temp = pd.DataFrame(df_data, index={counter},columns = [
            'Code',
            'Buy_date',
            'Buy',
            'Sell_date',
            'Sell',
            'Div_profit',
            'Gap',
            'TOTAL_PROFIT',
        ])
        counter +=1
        print (df_temp)
```

3 ITERATIONS OUTPUT EXAMPLE:

```
     Code   Buy_date    Buy  Sell_date   Sell Div_profit    Gap  TOTAL_PROFIT
0  CIE.MC 2018-01-03  21.66 2018-01-05  22.65      1,70%  46.13         63.13
     Code   Buy_date    Buy  Sell_date   Sell Div_profit   Gap  TOTAL_PROFIT
1  REE.MC 2018-01-03  18.27 2018-01-05  18.92      5,44%  35.3          89.7
     Code   Buy_date   Buy  Sell_date  Sell Div_profit   Gap  TOTAL_PROFIT
2  ZOT.MC 2018-01-08  9.33 2018-01-10  9.25      2,93% -8.57         20.73
```

Any idea of how can I join all the iterations in one big DF?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: you put all entries in a list & then structure the dataframe or simply use `pd.concat()` (not recommended - much slower/resource intensive)

Comment: if  use pd.concat() do I need a base df to start adding rows=

Comment: you just add your column names to a list.& make new df off it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> col_names = ['Code', 'Buy_date', 'Buy', 'Sell_date', 'Sell', 'Div_profit', 'Gap',  'TOTAL_PROFIT']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)

# within the loop:

df = pd.concat([df, df_temp])
```

Again, it is much better to contain all loop variables within a list out of which you should build your dataframe once (not using concat)

Comment: Oustanding sir!